# Row manipulation with large data set

Tags: r

I am trying to manipulate my data frame by either duplicating rows or multiplying them by 3. So, my data frame looks like so:

[image: This is only a small snippet - my full data has 1004 variables]

What I want to do is duplicate all the rows that have 2 of the same value (e.g. 1101), and for every row that only has one value (e.g. 1034 or 1056) I want to multiply that row by 3. So, ultimately I will have 3 of every singleton value and 4 of every double value.

I know how to duplicate the value using df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 2), ]. But, am unsure on how to specify to only duplicate the certain rows and to multiply the singleton rows by three.

I essentially what my data frame to ultimately be a data table that contains values like so: 1034, 1034, 1034, 1056, 1056, 1056, 1064, 1064, 1064, 1091, 1091, 1091, 1101, 1101, 1101, 1101 etc.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this replication process using `count` and `uncount`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Family_No = c(1034, 1056, 1064, 1101, 1101))


df %>%
  count(Family_No) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(n == 1, 3, 4)) %>%
  uncount(n) -> result

rownames(result) <- NULL
result

#   Family_No
#1       1034
#2       1034
#3       1034
#4       1056
#5       1056
#6       1056
#7       1064
#8       1064
#9       1064
#10      1101
#11      1101
#12      1101
#13      1101
```

Comment: This worked!! However, my data was automatically rearranged in ascending order - is there a way to prevent this rearrangement and ensure my data remains in the original order? 

Thanks,

Comment: You can turn those values to factor. Use `df %>% count(Family_No = factor(Family_No, unique(Family_No))) %>% ...rest of the code`